# Mock requests.post

Tags: python, pytest

I am using `pytest` to test a method that calls `requests.post`. Is there a easy way and preferably without third party libraries to do this?

```
class Dispatcher:
    def __init__(self, url):
    self.url = url
    self.session = None

    def dispatch(self):
        return self.session.post(self.url).json()


def test_dispatch():
    d = Dispatcher(url="")
    d.session = # ... here, how can I mock the return value of json()?
    result = d.dispatch()
```

Comment: set you instantiated class attribute of `session` to a `Mock` object and configure that `mock` object. are you aware how to do that?

Comment: no, this my doubt actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a pretty straightforward example. We want to set `session` to be a `MagicMock` object.

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

def test_dispatch():
    expected = {"fizz": "buzz"}
    mock_session = MagicMock()
    mock_session.configure_mock(
        **{
            "post.return_value": mock_session,
            "json.return_value": expected
        }
    )

    d = Dispatcher(url="")
    d.session = mock_session
    result = d.dispatch()

    assert result == expected
```

Since `Mock` objects return a *brand new* mock object when methods are called on them (without being configured), we have to configure the object as such. If we didn't configure `post` to return the original mock we have, then it would return a *brand new* mock object and our test would fail. Conversely you can configure another `Mock` object to be the return value of `post` and configure that object, but I prefer this approach.

Explanation showing the call is listed below.

`self.session` is our `mock_session` object we created

`self.session.post(arg, **kwargs)` returns `mock_session`

`mock_session.json()` returns the dictionary we specified

Comment: It is ok to use unittest.mock with pytest?

Comment: yes it is OK to use `unittest.mock` with `pytest`, I do it all the time. if you want to just stick to plugins, there is `pytest-mock` which enables fixtures for you to use that have `Mock` objects baked in to them